# Logical OR in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I´m new in Prolog learning and tried out a logical OR-operator for that context:

```
%a.      
b.

foo:- a ; b.
```

I have commented  `a.` to try out the logical OR-Operator but it does not work. If you query with `?-foo.` you get an exception. Prolog only checks the first term but not the second. Can anyone help me please?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

You get the exception as `a/0` is undefined. In order to check the or-operator you could explicitely define `a` as being false.

```
a:-false.
b.

foo:- a ; b.
```

Now `?- foo.` gives the answer `true.`

Prolog makes a 'closed world' assumption. It can only evaluate the trueness or falseness of a predicate that is defined. That means that you need at least one clause that has the predicate on its left hand side (or a fact, as this will be interpreted as a clausel with no condition thus without a right hand side).

Comment: But why is it obligatory to set for all variables a value? It should be possible with the variables as well because the logical AND-Operator works very good. I dont really get the idea of the Logical-OR in Prolog.

Comment: It is not the problem of the OR-operator, that works fine. It is the problem that Prolog makes a closed-world assumption. Try the query `?-c.` and you will get the same error about the undefined predicate c.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your reply. But how can I check facts like this:

foo(X,Y):- a(X,Y) ; b(X,Y).

I think that it isn´t possible to set a(X,Y) as true. With setting values for X and Y it doesn´t work neither.

Comment: Again, as long as you have at least one clause for a/2 and for b/2 everything is fine. You could have a(1,2), b(1,3) , then asking foo(1,3) gives you a true. I probably do not understand your question.

Comment: No. You have fully got my idea. I have a case that where the values are not directly assigned. I have one more step which is unknown facts without variables. Maybe thats why it does not work. I have the case below and want to make that query: ?-deriveB(tom,maxi).

Comment: Knowledgebase:
me(maxi,tim,2).
me(tom,leo,sense):-me(maxi,tim,2).
merge(tom,maxi,leo,tim,sense,2).

me_ee(X,Y):-me(X,_,_),merge(X,Y,_,_,_,_).
ee_me(X,Y):-ee(X,_,_),merge(X,Y,_,_,_,_).
ee_ee(X,Y):-ee(X,_,_),merge(X,Y,_,_,_,_).
me_me(X,Y):-me(X,_,_),merge(X,Y,_,_,_,_).

deriveA(X,Y):-me_ee(X,Y) ; ee_me(X,Y).
deriveA(X,Y):-ee_ee(X,Y) ; me_me(X,Y).
 
I get the same error like in the example before but why. Do you have a hint how to solve this? Best thanks !!!!

Comment: As far as I can see (the code is difficult to read), you have no definition of a ee/3 predicate. As soon as you define the predicate (even with some nonsense arguments), you get your desired result. Try adding `ee(1,1,1).` to your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially equivalent to:

```
foo :- a.
foo :- b.
```

The first clause tries to assess whether `foo` is true or not, by evaluating whether `a` is true or not. `a` doesn't even exist in the database, therefore you get an error.

Comment: Yes but I still have b which exists in the database. Because of the OR-operator. That has to be checked as well, right?

Comment: No. Think about it programmatically. In the first clause, Prolog is trying to see if it can evaluate whether `foo` is true or false. To do so, it needs to check whether `a` is true or false. `a` is undefined, so there's no way to evaluate it's truth value. It's not `false`. It's not even a "we don't know it could be either". It's undefined. It's a bug. You're trying to evaluate a variable that doesn't exist. It's the same with any language. Think of shortcut operators in c++ for instance, which is what I think you have in mind. `if(a || b)` will still throw an exception if `a` is undefined.

Comment: It also makes sense logically. If you were told: "Don't let anyone in unless the password they give you is correct. Btw I don't know the password". How do you deal with this? Do you let nobody in? Do you let everyone in? You can't just assume what they give you is either true or false if there's no defined password in your knowledge base to begin with. The most reasonable course of action is to complain and say "I'm sorry but I can't process that instruction until you give me a valid password to check against."